# Jquery attr not adding working id to buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, attr

Ok so i am doing a jquery project and for the site i need to add an edit but and a remove button through jquery when you "log in" using an xml document to store the username and pass word and jquery to check if it is valid one problem is after i add the buttons they do not work or get an id or pull up the intended module plz help

pannel 1

```
<div class='rows panel-place'>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4'>
         <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                        <div class='panel-title' id='panel1head'></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel-body'>
                        <ul id='panel1body'>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel-footer' id='panel1footer'>
                        <button id='add1' class='btn' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addamod1">Add Announcement</button>
                        <button id='link1' class='btn' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addlmod1">Add link</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
     </div>
```

where buttons are added

```
$('#p1adda').click(function(){

                edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                var input=$('#p1anounce').val();
                var date=$('#p1date').val();
                var node=$('<li></li>').text(input+" "+date).attr("id","p1"+m);
                $('#panel1body').prepend(node)
                $('#panel1body').children().first().prepend(edit)
                $('#panel1body').children().first().prepend(remove)
                m++;

            });//end of announce p1 click
```

this is just some of the code also ik i can shorten the attr part by putting it in {}

bc i am new and dont know exactly what to post here is my entire code
also before the ul is the jquery and bootstrap links but it would not let me show it also is the begining of the first panel looks like other two also there where two more add link pannels look like the first but diff id's

```
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel-footer' id='panel1footer'>
                        <button id='add1' class='btn' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addamod1">Add Announcement</button>
                        <button id='link1' class='btn' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addlmod1">Add link</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
     </div>
     <!--panel 2-->

     <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4'>
         <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                        <div class='panel-title' id='panel2head'></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel-body'>
                        <ul id='panel2body'>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel-footer' id='panel2footer'>
                        <button id='add2' class='btn' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addamod2">Add Announcement</button>
                        <button id='link2' class='btn' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addlmod2">Add link</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
     </div>
     <!--panel 3-->
     <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4'>
         <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                        <div class='panel-title' id='panel3head'></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel-body'>
                        <ul id='panel3body'>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class='panel-footer' id='panel3footer'>
                        <button id='add3' class='btn' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addamod3">Add Announcement</button>
                        <button id='link3' class='btn' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addlmod3">Add link</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
     </div>
     </div>
</body>
<!--panel end-->
<body class='bg'>

    <div class='container' style='margin-top:70px'>
        <nav class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top'>
          <div class='container'>
            <div class='navbar-header'>
                <div class='navbar-brand'><img src='Images/cfire.png' class='img img-responsive logo' style='float:left' /> &nbsp Camp Shoobs</div>
                <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#mainNav'>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='mainNav'>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                    <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Activities</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                    <li> 
                    <form>
                        <div id='logout' class='btn btn-success'>Log out</div>
                        <div id='login' class='btn btn-success'>Login</div>
                        <input type='text' id='user' placeholder='username' />
                        <input type='password' id='password' placeholder='password' />
                    </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
           </div>
        </nav>

        </div>

   <!--nav end-->

   <!-- Add Announcement 1 -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="addamod1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ALabel1">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h5 class="modal-title modal-primary" id="ALabel1">Add Anouncement</h5>
      </div>
      <form>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea type='textarea' id='p1anounce' rows='5' cols='70' placeholder='Enter Anouncement Here' required='required'></textarea>
        <input type='date' id=p1date required='required'/>
      </div>
      </form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id='p1adda' class="btn btn-success" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" >Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

   <!-- Add Announcement 2 -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="addamod2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ALabel2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h5 class="modal-title modal-primary" id="ALabel2">Add Anouncement</h5>
      </div>
      <form>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea type='textarea' id='p2anounce' rows='5' cols='70' placeholder='Enter Anouncement Here' required='required'></textarea>
        <input type='date' id=p2date required='required'/>
      </div>
      </form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id='p2adda' class="btn btn-success" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Add Announcement 3 -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="addamod3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ALabel3">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h5 class="modal-title modal-primary" id="ALabel3">Add Anouncement</h5>
      </div>
      <form>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea type='textarea' id='p3anounce' rows='5' cols='70' placeholder='Enter Anouncement Here' required='required'></textarea>
        <input type='date' id=p2date required='required'/>
      </div>
      </form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id='p3adda' class="btn btn-success" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Add Link 1 -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="addlmod1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lLabel1">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h5 class="modal-title modal-primary" id="lLabel1">Add Link</h5>
      </div>
      <form>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type='text' id='p1text' placeholder='Enter Text You Want Linked Here' required='required'/>
        <input type='text' id='p1link' placeholder='Enter Link' required='required'/>
      </div>
      </form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id='p1addl' class="btn btn-success" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>



  <!-- Edit text -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="editmod" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lLabel3">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h5 class="modal-title modal-primary" id="lLabel3">Edit text</h5>
      </div>
      <form>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea type='textarea' id='TextBox' rows='5' cols='50' required='required'></textarea>
      </div>
      </form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id='Editit' class="btn btn-success" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" >Edit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

          $('#add1').hide()
          $('#add2').hide()
          $('#add3').hide()

          $('#link1').hide()
          $('#link2').hide()
          $('#link3').hide()
           $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'PanelInfo.xml',
            Datatype:'xml',
            success: function(result){
                var x=0;
                var y=1;
                $(result).find('panel').each(function(){

                    var title=$(this).find('name').text()
                    //alert(title)
                    var nodes=$('<div></div>').text(title)


                    if(x==0){
                        //alert('in 1')
                        $('#panel1head').append(nodes)
                    }else if(x==1){
                        $('#panel2head').append(nodes)
                        //alert('in 2')
                    }else if(x==2){
                        $('#panel3head').append(nodes)
                        //alert('in 3')
                    }
                    x++;
                    $(result).find('event').each(function() {
                        //alert('why');
                        if(y<=9){
                        //alert('hi')    
                        var event=$(this).text();
                        var enode=$('<li></li>').text(event);
                        //alert('hello');
                        var d=y-3;
                        var e=y-6;
                        if(y<=3){
                            $(enode).attr('id','p1'+y);
                            $('#panel1body').append(enode);
                            //alert('1');
                        }else if(y<=6){
                            $(enode).attr('id','p2'+d);
                            $('#panel2body').append(enode);
                            //alert('2');
                        }else if(y<=9){
                            $(enode).attr('id','p3'+e);
                            $('#panel3body').append(enode);
                            //alert('3');
                        }
                        y++;
                        //alert(event);
                        }
                    });//end each
            });//end each

            }//end result  
           });//end ajax

          //start variables
           $('#logout').hide()
           var x=0;
           var name, username, password;
           var Camper=false;
           var Councilor=false;
           var Supervisor=false;
           var Owner=false;
           var person;
           var user=false;
           var edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit");
           var remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
           var z=1;
           var m=4;
           var n=4;
           var o=4;
            //alert('Remove'+$(remove).attr('id'))
         //end variables

            $('#login').click(function(){
                var login=false;
                x=0;
                $.ajax({
                    type:'GET',
                    url:'users.xml',
                    Datatype:'xml',
                    success: function(result){
                        $(result).find('user').each(function(){




                        if($('#user').val()==$(this).find('username').text()&&$('#password').val()==$(this).find('password').text()){

                            password = $('#password').val();
                            username = $('#user').val();
                            name=$(this).find('name').text();
                            user=true;
                        //alert(user+'hi');
                        }//end if statment
                        });//end each

                        //alert(name);
                                if(name=="Councilor"){
                                    Councilor=true;
                                    //alert("councilor");
                                   for(z=1;z<=$('#panel2body').children().length;z++){
                                       edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                                       remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                                       $('#p2'+z).prepend(edit)
                                       $('#p2'+z).prepend(remove)
                                   }//end p2 for
                                }
                                else if(name=="Camper"){
                                    Camper=true;
                                    //alert("camper");
                                    for(z=1;z<=$('#panel1body').children().length;z++){
                                       edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                                       remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                                       $('#p1'+z).prepend(edit)
                                       $('#p1'+z).prepend(remove)
                                   }//end p2 for
                                }
                                else if(name=="Supervisor"){
                                    Supervisor=true;
                                    //alert("supervisor");
                                   for(z=1;z<=$('#panel2body').children().length;z++){
                                       edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                                       remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                                       $('#p3'+z).prepend(edit)
                                       $('#p3'+z).prepend(remove)
                                   }//end p2 for
                                }
                                else if(name=="Owner"){
                                    Owner=true;
                                    //alert("owner");
                                    //1
                                   for(z=1;z<=$('#panel1body').children().length;z++){
                                       edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                                       remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                                       $('#p1'+z).prepend(edit)
                                       $('#p1'+z).prepend(remove)
                                   }//end p1 for
                                    //2
                                    for(z=1;z<=$('#panel2body').children().length;z++){
                                       edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                                       remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                                       $('#p2'+z).prepend(edit)
                                       $('#p2'+z).prepend(remove)
                                   }//end p2 for
                                    //3
                                   for(z=1;z<=$('#panel3body').children().length;z++){
                                       edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                                       remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                                       $('#p3'+z).prepend(edit)
                                       $('#p3'+z).prepend(remove)
                                   }//end p3 for
                                }

                           if(user==true){
                                login=true;
                                //alert("login");                                    
                                $('#login').hide()
                                $('#user').hide()
                                $('#password').hide()
                                $('#logout').show()
                                $('#logout').text("Logout")
                                var node=$("<div></div>").text("User: "+name).attr('id', 'Person')
                                $('#logout').after(node)

                                if(Camper==true){
                                    $('#add1').show()
                                    $('#link1').show()
                                }else if(Councilor==true){
                                    $('#add2').show()
                                    $('#link2').show()
                                }else if(Supervisor==true){
                                    $('#add3').show()
                                    $('#link3').show()
                                }else if(Owner==true){
                                    $('#add1').show()
                                    $('#add2').show()
                                    $('#add3').show()

                                    $('#link1').show()
                                    $('#link2').show()
                                    $('#link3').show()
                                }
                    }//end user if statment
                    else if(user==false){
                        alert('Invalid Username or Passeord');
                    }//end else
                        }//end success

                });//end ajax
            });//login click

            //if the button id's worked this would be the code i would use for remove
            $('#gone').click(function(){
                    $(this).parent().remove()
            });//end remove click
            //if the buttons id worked for edit this is code i would use
            $('#edit').click(function(){
                    var box=$(this).parent().text()
                    $('#Textbox').val(box)
            });//end edit click


            $('#p1adda').click(function(){

                edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                var input=$('#p1anounce').val();
                var date=$('#p1date').val();
                var node=$('<li></li>').text(input+" "+date).attr("id","p1"+m);
                $('#panel1body').prepend(node)
                $('#panel1body').children().first().prepend(edit)
                $('#panel1body').children().first().prepend(remove)
                m++;
            });//end of announce p1 click

            $('#p2adda').click(function(){

                edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                var input=$('#p2anounce').val();
                var date=$('#p2date').val();
                var node=$('<li></li>').text(input+" "+date).attr("id","p2"+n);
                $('#panel2body').prepend(node)
                $('#panel2body').children().first().prepend(edit)
                $('#panel2body').children().first().prepend(remove)
                n++;
            });//end of announce p2 click

            $('#p3adda').click(function(){

                edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                var input=$('#p3anounce').val();
                var date=$('#p3date').val();
                var node=$('<li></li>').text(input+" "+date).attr("id","p3"+o);
                $('#panel3body').prepend(node)
                $('#panel3body').children().first().prepend(edit)
                $('#panel3body').children().first().prepend(remove)
                o++;
            });//end of announce p3 click 

            $('#p1addl').click(function(){

                edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                var text=$('#p1text').val();
                var link=$('#p1link').val();
                var node=$('<a><li></li></a>').text(text).attr('href',"https://"+link).attr("id","p1"+m);
                $('#panel1body').prepend(node)
                $('#panel1body').children().first().prepend(edit)
                $('#panel1body').children().first().prepend(remove)
                m++;
            });//end of link p1 click

             $('#p2addl').click(function(){
                edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                var text=$('#p2text').val();
                var link=$('#p2link').val();
                var node=$('<a><li></li></a>').text(text).attr('href',"https://"+link).attr("id","p2"+n);
                $('#panel2body').prepend(node)
                $('#panel2body').children().first().prepend(edit)
                $('#panel2body').children().first().prepend(remove)
                n++;
            });//end of link p2 click

             $('#p3addl').click(function(){
                edit=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-edit').attr("id","edit").attr("data-toggle","modal").attr("data-target","editmod");
                remove=$('<button></button>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').css('color','red').attr("id","gone");
                var text=$('#p3text').val();
                var link=$('#p3link').val();
                var node=$('<a><li></li></a>').text(text).attr('href',"https://"+link).attr("id","p3"+o);
                $('#panel3body').prepend(node)
                $('#panel3body').children().first().prepend(edit)
                $('#panel3body').children().first().prepend(remove)
                o++;
            });//end of link p3 click

            $('#logout').click(function(){
                $('#login').show()
                $('#user').show()
                $('#password').show()
                $('#logout').hide()
                $('#Person').remove()

                $('#add1').hide()
                $('#add2').hide()
                $('#add3').hide()

                $('#link1').hide()
                $('#link2').hide()
                $('#link3').hide()

                Owner=false;
                Camper=false;
                Supervisor=false;
                Councilor=false;

                $('li button').remove()
                $('a li').remove()
            });//logout click


        });//end of ready
        $('#add1').click(function(){

        });//end of add 1 click
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Noah,

Your event listeners are applied to the HTML once the DOM is rendered, or on document.ready essentially.
If I am seeing this correctly, once you prepend the elements & buttons after clicking ADD there is

1. not an event listener added to the newly prepended elements
2. or there is not an event listener on a parent element that is already on the page from initial load, listening for an event to 'bubble up'

   If its the latter you can specifically look for that element with ***$(^parentElement^).on('click', '#edit', ()=>{});***....you will want to replace the ^parentElement^ with the element you want.

if you have multiple of the same elements, you will have to add a unique identifier--possibly.  This can be avoided by prepending with an event listener attached but not the method I prefer, some one else on here may though.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok so i need to make an event listener for the new prepended things. In the code you gave me what does this do ()=>{} do i know put the events i want to happen on click in there also thanks for trying to help me i greatly appreciate it.